# SQL friends-relations one-way/ both-way system

Tags: sql

I am creating kind of social site with friends and I have tables with users and friends relations

```
FRIENDS
id          iduser     idfriend
0             44           56
1             44          102
2             10           66
3             10           85
4             44           10
5             10           44
6             56           44

LOGIN
id         jmeno               email       isonline
44         john          john@gmail.com           1
10         joe           joe@yahoo.com            1
185        mark          mark@so.com              0
```

When user connect he request from server his friends which are online and I use this SQL command for that

```
SELECT u.id, 
       jmeno, 
       email 
  FROM friends f 
       INNER JOIN login u 
           ON f.idfriend = u.id 
 WHERE f.iduser = 44 
       AND u.online =1
```

But I realized that this is not the right solution because when user 44 and user 10 wants to be friends there has to be both relations like:

```
    44  -  10 
    10  -  44
```

I just want to select the relation just from one line in database
So find the id in iduser and in idfriend eithe. Now im using this one-way relations sql up here.

Comment: This approach might be not efficient on terms of storage space, but at least you can find friends for a user via single field "iduser" in "Friends" table. If you will have only one row for each friend pair, then you will have to check also "idfriend", which will take additional time.

Answer (score 1):

Your current schema is not necessarily a bad thing.  That is how I would design the relationship.

The Friends table is a standard cross-reference table.  If the friend relationship is severed, you need to clean up both sides, but that is easy.  It allows you to join to one column, `id`, and get the correct `idfriend` at once.  It also makes for an easy constraint to guarantee uniqueness.

Your current schema also allows for (10, 44) meaning 10 wants to be friends with 44, but if (44, 10) is not there, then maybe 44 does not want to be friends with 10.  But then maybe that is not a business requirement.

If you want (10, 44) to be equivalent to (44, 10), then when creating the relationship, you will have to do add an additional query to look at both sides and ensure the existing relationship does not exist.

You an do this with an `OR` in the join clause or with a UNION.  Joe's code looks good to me.  You might also look into a view (or indexed view) here.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to do it.  One is to do an `or` inside the join, so that you're joining on `iduser` or `idfriend`:

```
select
    u.*
from
    login u
    join friends f 
     on (u.id = f.iduser 
         and f.idfriend = 44)
     or (u.id = idfriend
         and f.iduser = 44)
where
  u.id != 44;
```

Another method is to create a subquery that creates a listing of *all* bi-directional friend relationships, then selects from it:

```
select
  *
from 
 (select
      iduser,
      u.*
  from
      friends f
      inner join login u on f.idfriend = u.id
  union
  select
      idfriend,
      u.*
  from
      friends f
      inner join login u on f.iduser = u.id) q
where
  q.iduser = 44
  and q.isonline = 1
```

You didn't specify which database engine you're using -- if you are using one that supports CTEs (Oracle or SQL Server, for example), the subquery could be instead done in a CTE.

The second method is more resource-intensive, but only requires one change to the code to select a different ID.

All three queries are in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e704a/14), but I removed the existing bi-directional friendships in order to illustrate the logic.